# Problem of the pdf plot for Weibull distribution

Tags: weibull-distribution

I'm using MATLAB to plot the Weibull distribution function. But the y-axis, obviously, is not probability. Also, the plot on Wikipedia ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution))has same y-axis as mine, so my question is: **is there something wrong here?** I'm pretty sure that my code is correct. So Why the y-axis is not probability ?[image]

Comment: Because this is probability density function...

Comment: density is not probability